# LINQ building array with multiple values per select

Tags: c#, linq, yaml

I have been trying to build a YAML Node with the yamlserializer library. But I am having difficulty constructing a LINQ statement.

I have a list of "Category" objects, lets call it "Cats", the Category class has both an Id and a Name that need to be represented in the following way as Yaml Mappings.
Cats[0].Id : Cats[0]Name
Cats[1].Id : Cats[1].Name
...

For those that haven't worked with the library.
the class YamlMapping has a constructor that takes an array of YamlNode objects.
YamlNode is an abstract class from which all types of nodes including YamlMapping inherit.

```
new YamlMapping
(
    "Categories", new YamlMapping (
    (from cat in blacklist.Categories.List select
    (YamlNode)cat.Id AND (YamlNode)cat.Name).ToArray());
)
```

The above obviously does not work, and I was wondering if there is any way to achieve the desired result.
It would be possible to construct the arrays before hand but was wondering if there is a more LINQish (?) way of achieving the same effect.

In other words the array build would have to be something like this.

```
YamlNode[] arr;
arr[0] = Cats[0].Id
arr[1] = Cats[0].Name;
arr[2] = Cats[1].Id;
arr[3] = Cats[1].Name;
......
```

Answer (score 2):

Something like :

```
(from cat in blacklist.Categories.List select
new YamlNode[] { (YamlNode)cat.Id, (YamlNode)cat.Name }).SelectMany(x => x).ToArray());
```

should do the trick.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to select a sequence (in this case, a pair) of items per item into a single flat sequence, use `SelectMany`:

```
YamlNode[] arr = blacklist.Categories.List
    .SelectMany(cat => new[] { (YamlNode)cat.Id, (YamlNode)cat.Name })
    .ToArray();
```